# Which methods should I lock when creating a thread-safe ArrayList

Tags: c, multithreading, arraylist, race-condition

I am creating an ArrayList in c with the following methods.

```
//Creates a new list with each object being dataSize
ArrayList* newList(int dataSize);

//adds an element to the list
int add(ArrayList *list, void* data);

//returns the index of an element
int getIndex(ArrayList *list, void* data);

//returns the element at the given index
void* getData(ArrayList *self, int index);

//Removes the given data from the list and shifts the list to the left
bool removeData(ArrayList *list, void *data);

//Removes the data at the index from the list and shifts the list to the left
void *remove_index_al(ArrayList *list, int index);

//Frees the list
void freeList(ArrayList *list);

//resizes the list
static bool resize(ArrayList* list)
```

I want to make my arraylist thread safe by adding

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&self->mutex);
```

and

```
pthread_mutex_unlock(&self->mutex);
```

at the beginning and end of each method.

However, I don't just want to add them to every single method. I only want to add them where needed. Which of these methods would be needed to be locked and unlocked to prevent race conditions?

Currently I have resize and add locked but I don't think I need to lock newList. Do I need to lock and unlock all the other methods to ensure synchronization?

Comment: Any code fragment that modifies any ArrayList field must be enclosed in lock/unlock, especially if the modification is based on a condition check.

Comment: @dyz should the lock be before or after the condition check?

Comment: The purpose of the lock is to ensure that the value of condition does not change before the action is completed. So, before.